npm start -> Module build failed
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Undefined variable: "$bpk-spacing-lg".
on line 13 of src/App.scss


padding: $bpk-spacing-lg * 2;



I run 'npm start' on terminal to get access to localhost:3000. cannot find solution to the undefined variable '$bpk-spacing-lg'.

Create variable in the same scss file: $bpk-spacing-lg=10;
